# Example of libgdx working with google app engine as backend

Tags: google-app-engine, libgdx

I used libgdx in the past and it's awesome, and now I'm learning to use GAE, but I can't find any example of GAE+Libgdx implementation, Is it posible? I mean, there is a way(or ways) to <s>achieve this</s> run backend service on GAE for libgdx?

A link could be usefull too :)

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?  Do you want to run a backend service for your game on GAE?

Comment: Exactly. I will update the post.

Answer (score 1):

The API between your Libgdx app and the GAE service would just be an HTTP connection, I think.  So the only real support in Libgdx is via the [Libgdx Net API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.html).  There isn't anything specific about GAE as the backend though, any HTTP service would work.